Curve integral $\int_\gamma y^2 dx + x^2 dy$
Problem:
$$
\int_\gamma y^2 dx + x^2 dy
$$
where $\gamma$ is the circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2$ through a lap counterclockwise.
I use Green's theorem and put $x = a + r\cos \phi, y= b + r\sin \phi, P=y^2, Q=x^2$, which give me the integral of form
$$
\iint_D (2x-2y) dxdy = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2(a+r \cos \phi - b - r \sin \phi) r dr d\phi = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2(a-b)r + 2r^2(\cos \phi - \sin \phi)dr d\phi
$$
$$
= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2(a-b)r drd\phi + \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2r^2(\cos \phi-\sin \phi)drd\phi = 2\pi(a-b)+\frac{2}{3} \bigg[ \sin \phi + \cos \phi \bigg]_0^{2\pi}
$$
$$
= 2\pi(a-b) \neq 2\pi r^2(a-b) = solution.
$$
I cannot figure out what I missed. Thanks.
Sincerely, TS

Using $r$ as both a constant and a variable is a terrible idea.

Could you please clarify, I'm a bit confused. Thx.

The radius of the circle should be $R$ (change the letter in the problem). Then in your double integral $r$ goes from $0$ to $R$.

Your computations are correct, except for the fact that $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $r$ and not 1, that is why the non-vanishing integral should be replaced by
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi \int_0^\color{red}{r}\mathrm{d}r \; 2(a-b)r = 2\pi r^2(a-b)
$$

If $r$ is the upper bound of the innter integral, the integrating variable should be rnamed to avoid confusion.

@Snake707  Sure, but this notation is also quite common in applied sciences in order to avoid to handle too many variables when no confusion threatens the future computations.

Thank you so much for input. One question: why is the r outside of the integral? Shouldn't it be
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi 2(a-b) \int_0^r r dr = 4\pi (a-b) \bigg[ \frac{r^2}{2} \bigg]_0^r = 2\pi (a-b)r^2 ?
$$
Am I missing something? Thx again!

@TerribleStudent  You're right. Actually, that is another conventional notation with multidimensional integration, mostly encountered in physics contexts, where the integrand is pushed out to the far right.

@Abezhiko Thank you very much, I'm still trying to learn all of this stuff.
